# Proof: Elimination of the geometrical phase factors in the adiabatic approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

#### Instantaneous eigenstates

$$H(t)|\psi_{n}(t)\rangle = E_{n}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$

Time evolution of the general quantum state can be cast in the form
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum\limits_n a_n(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$

From Schrodinger equation we get
$$\dot{a}_n(t) = \left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_{n}(t)-\langle \psi_n(t)| \dot{\psi}_{n}(t)\rangle \right]a_n(t) - \sum\limits_{m \neq n}a_m(t)\frac{\langle \psi_m(t)| \dot{H}(t) | \psi_{n}(t)}{E_{n}(t) - E_{m}(t)}$$
In the adiabatic approximation we neglect the summation part and arrive at the approximate solution:
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum\limits_{n}a_{n}(0)e^{i\left[\theta_{n}(t) + \gamma_n(t) \right]}|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$
where
$$\theta_n(t) = -\frac{1}{\hbar}\int\limits_{0}^{t}dt'\ E_{n}(t')$$
$$\gamma_n(t) = i\int\limits_{0}^{t}dt'\ \langle \psi_{n}(t') | \dot{\psi}_{n}(t') \rangle$$.

#### Different choice of eigenstates

$$H(t)e^{i\phi_n(t)}|\psi_{n}(t)\rangle = E_{n}(t)e^{i\phi_n(t)}|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$

Time evolution of the general quantum state can be cast in the form
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum\limits_n b_n(t)e^{i\phi_n(t)}|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$

Following the same pattern as before we get
$$\dot{b}_n(t) = \left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_{n}(t) -i\dot{\phi}_n(t)-\langle \psi_n(t)| \dot{\psi}_{n}(t)\rangle \right]b_n(t) - \sum\limits_{m \neq n}b_m(t)\frac{\langle \psi_m(t)| \dot{H}(t) | \psi_{n}(t)}{E_{n}(t) - E_{m}(t)}$$
In the adiabatic approximation we throw out the summation part and get the following result
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum\limits_{n}b_n(0)e^{i\theta_n(t)}e^{i\left[\gamma_n(t) + \phi_n(0) \right]}|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$
It seems there is no way I can eliminate geometrical phase factor just by introducing extra phase factors.

Do you know a correct proof showing that geometrical phase is not important?

Comment: Why would the geometric phase not be important? (Perhaps, I've missed the context.)

Comment: Barry L. Holstein "Topics in advanced quantum mechanics": "However, it was always assumed that $\gamma_n(t)$ could be eliminated be redefining the phase of the eigenstate $|\psi_n\rangle$".

Comment: Basically, in every quantum mechanics book I see the same sentence without any proof.

Comment: Ah, now I think I get it. It is not an overall phase that is removed, but the phase of the individual eigenstates. That should be valid, because such a phase has no physical effect. In effect one can always say $|\psi\rangle\equiv\exp(i\alpha)|\psi\rangle$.